# PayPal MPL library payment options is too small

Tags: android, paypal

Paypal MPL library payment options is too small.How to fix it? Thanks.
[image]

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: Also, are you using the latest version of MPL?  A similar issue was fixed within the past year.